# Is there a way to display content on same page after a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my content to display on the same page as my button. But when i enter the values and press display the square i am forming is displayed on a new white webpage.

I ask the user to enter two values (height and width), I also ask for a character to form the border of the square, but i have not been able to do that part yet so i just hard coded a # character in for the border in the meantime

What i would like to know is how to display my square on the same page and not in a seperate page.

I use an external JavaScript file: Here is its code. Its named "SquareScript.js":

```
function Display()
{
var a = document.getElementById("value1").value;
var b = document.getElementById("value2").value;
var outputText = "";

for (var i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
outputText += "#";
}

outputText +="<br>";
for (var r = 0; r < b; r++)
{
outputText += "#";


for(var p = 0; p < a-2; p++)
{
outputText +="&nbsp&nbsp";
}
outputText += "#";
outputText +="<br>";
}

for (var i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
outputText += "#";
}

}
```

Here is my webpages code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Assignment3.css">
        <style>
            table {background-color:white;color:black;}
            body {background-image: url('squares.png');}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "heading">
            <h1><img src = "Interested.png" width = 100px height = 100px></img>WELCOME TO BUILD A   SQUARE</h1>
        </div>

        <script src = "SquareScript.js">
        </script>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Please Enter value number 1:&nbsp&nbsp<input type = "text" id = "value1">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    Please Enter value number 2:&nbsp&nbsp<input type = "text" id = "value2">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    Please Enter a character:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type = "text"     id = "character"> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button onclick = "Display()">Display</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <div id="output" style = "background-color:blue;"><script>
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML(outputText);
    </script></div>

 </table>
    </body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</html>
```

Any useful tips will be appreciated and please consider the fact that I am still new to web development so my code is obviously very basic. Please let me know if you require anything more of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `document.write()` works is that when it's called outside the HTML page, it automatically creates a new document and writes into that (see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)).  This is what's going on in your case: the function is called outside of the HTML (in SquareScript.js) and so it's making a new document, which is the "new white webpage" you're seeing.

You could solve this problem by calling `document.write()` from within the HTML page.  Or you could forego using `document.write()` and instead reference an element on the existing page (a more flexible solution).  By creating a new element in your HTML where the output of your functions should appear (like `<div id="output"></div>`), you can use `document.getElementById("output")` to put your script's output into that element.

You don't need to call this every time you want to add content. Instead, create a new variable to hold your output text as you generate it.

```
var outputText = "";
```

Then as you go through your loops, you can add to `outputText`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    outputText += "#";
}
```

Then after all your loops are complete, you can insert the content into the output `div` by making the following function call as the last thing in your `display()` function:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML(outputText);
```

Comment: So i will pu this in my for loop: document.getElementById("output").innerHTML("#"); ?

Comment: @AndreSmith that will work - as long as you add an element with `id="output"` to the HTML first.  For example, you could add `<div id="output"></div>` or `<span id="output"></span>`.

Comment: I have modified my code to do it the way i think you are saying i should. but it is not working

Comment: @AndreSmith instead of replacing every `document.write()` with `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML("#")`, add all your output content to a holding variable and insert its contents into the HTML at the very end of your script.  See my updated answer for more information.

Comment: The content is still displayed on a separate page. Im sorry I updated my code again. I prob am not understanding you correctly?

Comment: @AndreSmith you should put the code which inserts the content at the end of the `Display()` function in SquareScript.js, rather than within the `<div id="output"></div>` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `document.write`. Create `<div id="result"></div>` on your page and place your output there. You should create a string variable containing your HTML output. Then you can display this HTML using the following code:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = my_html_output;
```

Comment: so i will do this in the for loops? when i am trying to display the #?

Comment: Add `var my_html_output;` to the start of your function, and replace any `document.write(something)` with `my_html_output += something;`.